# What is the expected value and variance for this variable?

Tags: regression, bayesian, kalman-filter

I read about a formula in a textbook called Recursive Macroeconomic Theory and am quite confused about it. In this formula, you observe $y$, which equals $\theta + u$. The distributions of $\theta$ and $u$ are known. $\theta \sim N(\mu,\sigma_0^2)$, $u \sim  N(0,\sigma_1^2)$. The goal is to infer the expected value, $m_0$ and variance, $\sigma_1$ of $\theta$ conditional on $y$.

The text book gives the formula for $m_0=\mu+\frac{\sigma_0^2}{\sigma_0^2+\sigma_1^2}(y-u)$. It claims that this formula can be derived from Kalman filter.

I am quite confused about the claim related to using Kalman filter. Why is this related to Kalman filter? Isn't this a simple bayesian updating problem?

Comment: Kalman filter in a sense is a simple Bayesian updating exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a Bayesian update. When in the context of a time series of observations $y_t \sim p_y(\theta_t)$ and $\theta_t \sim p_\theta(\theta_{t-1})$, the filtered distributions $p(\theta_t|y_1,\ldots,y_t)$ can be called a Bayes filter. The Kalman filter is a Bayes filter when $p_y(\cdot)$ and $p_\theta(\cdot)$ are linear and normal, as in the example you gave.